# Artillery test script exits without waiting for artillery-plugin-datadog to finish flushing

Tags: datadog, artillery

I have an Artillery test script which uses artillery-plugin-datadog for periodically flushing metrics to Datadog.

In shell script:

```
export DEBUG=metrics,plugin:datadog
```

In artillery yml file:

```
plugins:
  datadog:
    prefix: "artillery.[my-prefix]."
    tags:
      ...
```

However, it looks like Artillery does not wait for plugin to complete the metrics sending and exits process when test scenario is complete. I see in logs that plugin initiates flushing of metrics, but they do not reach DD:

```
  metrics Flushing 31 metrics to DataDog +12s
  metrics Calling add_metrics with ...
```

In short scenarios I was not able to get any metrics in DD. In longer scenarios last couple of metric flushes always do not appear in DD.

Is there any way to tell Artillery to wait for plugin flushing before exiting test process? I didn't found anything about it in documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately this is a [known issue](https://github.com/bigbank-as/artillery-plugin-datadog/issues/5) with `artillery-plugin-datadog`, which seems abandoned. I took a quick look and the call to flush the stats is not synchronous.

Consider using [artillery-plugin-publish-metrics](https://github.com/artilleryio/artillery-plugin-publish-metrics) instead.

Comment: Thanks for response! Unfortunately, suggested plugin shows exact same behavior by not sending all the metrics. Also, with `publish-metrics` I experience connection errors periodically: `plugin:publish-metrics:datadog-statsd Error: read ECONNRESET
  plugin:publish-metrics:datadog-statsd     at TLSWrap.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:209:20) +287ms`

Comment: I'd suggest opening an issue on GitHub. Since this is an officially supported library from Artillery, they should be able to guide you.